# WebAps - Monolith architecture Or Microservice Architecture, pros and cons?

Tags: java, microservices, monolithic

We are creating a new solution having some business entities like, financiers, contracts, device financing, payments. We mainly have 5-6 domain objects.

So which kind of architecture we should be going with, which has better adaptability in future and lesser maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

So there is no quick and definitive answer here,
The final decision will depend on some factors,

- technical; like (but not limited to) how will the application scale? or does it require scaling? how will it be deployed or monitored ?? how much changes are expected to happen in the future? are many teams working on it??
- business, and this also comes before technical,(also not limited to) how many users are expected? how heavy is the business requirements changing??.

As per my own experience, most projects don't start as microservices projects in the beginning, they start as either a monolith or a what so called (SCS) self contained systems(careful on using this).

Microservices offer you nice scaling and distributed capabilities, and (MAY) improve the overall performance if well architectured, they also suit huge projects with large number of teams where every teams manage a set of microservices. but on the other hand they come with difficulties to deploy and monitor and it needs a huge infrastructure capabilities to be able to handle a ms project.

On the other hand, Monoliths or semi-monoliths (like self contained systems), they look easier to deploy and get running quickly, but for a huge number of user-base you will do a lot of refactorings on the long run to improve performance here and there. But they are easy to handle by a small team  with no great infrastructure capabilities.

Of course there are a huge tons if information and opinions here, this is just a very small piece of my experience.